# How to get SPARQL's ASK answer from query done with sparqllib?

Tags: php, sparql

The `SPARQL`'s `ASK` query that is done on the code below returns `true` when I execute it at [Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). The same result is what I want returned to my script. How can I adapt the **sparqllib** use?

```
<?php
    require_once('./sparqllib.php');
    $db = sparql_connect('http://dbpedia.org/sparql');

    $query = "
    ASK {
        ?book a dbpedia-owl:Book .
        ?book dbpprop:author ?author .
        ?book dbpprop:name ?bookname .
        ?author dbpprop:name ?authorname .
        FILTER regex(?bookname, 'A Tale of Two Cities', 'i') .
        FILTER regex(?authorname, 'Dickens', 'i')
    }";

    $result = sparql_query($query);
    var_dump($result);
```

---

`var_dump()`'s result:

```
object(sparql_result)[3]
  public 'rows' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'fields' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'db' => 
    object(sparql_connection)[1]
      public 'db' => null
      public 'debug' => boolean false
      public 'errno' => null
      public 'error' => null
      public 'ns' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'params' => null
      public 'caps' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'caps_desc' => 
        array (size=7)
          'select' => string 'Basic SELECT' (length=12)
          'constant_as' => string 'SELECT ("foo" AS ?bar)' (length=22)
          'math_as' => string 'SELECT (2+3 AS ?bar)' (length=20)
          'count' => string 'SELECT (COUNT(?a) AS ?n) ?b ... GROUP BY ?b' (length=43)
          'max' => string 'SELECT (MAX(?a) AS ?n) ?b ... GROUP BY ?b' (length=41)
          'sample' => string 'SELECT (SAMPLE(?a) AS ?n) ?b ... GROUP BY ?b' (length=44)
          'load' => string 'LOAD <...>' (length=10)
      public 'caps_cache' => null
      public 'caps_anysubject' => null
      public 'endpoint' => string 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql' (length=25)
  public 'i' => int 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer (workaround)

sparqllib.php doesn't appear to support processing the results of `ask` queries, so you should probably just use

```
select * where {
    ?book a dbpedia-owl:Book .
    ?book dbpprop:author ?author .
    ?book dbpprop:name ?bookname .
    ?author dbpprop:name ?authorname .
    FILTER regex(?bookname, 'A Tale of Two Cities', 'i') .
    FILTER regex(?authorname, 'Dickens', 'i')
}
limit 1
```

and check whether you get a result.

### Long answer (sparqllib doesn't support `ask` results)

I don't think that sparqllib supports queries other than `select` queries.  If you take a look at [sparqllib.php](http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/download.php/sparqllib.php), you can see how the query gets executed:

```
function query( $query, $timeout=null )
{   
    $prefixes = "";
    foreach( $this->ns as $k=>$v )
    {
        $prefixes .= "PREFIX $k: <$v>\n";
    }
    $output = $this->dispatchQuery( $prefixes.$query, $timeout );
    if( $this->errno ) { return; }
    $parser = new xx_xml($output, 'contents');
    if( $parser->error() ) 
    { 
        $this->errno = -1; # to not clash with CURLOPT return; }
        $this->error = $parser->error();
        return;
    }
    return new sparql_result( $this, $parser->rows, $parser->fields );
}
```

`dispatchQuery` is responsible for sending the query and getting the results back.  It asks for them in `application/sparql-results+xml`, and that's why an XML parser gets involved. If you take a look at the XML parsing code, there's stuff like:

```
function startXML($parser, $name, $attr)    
{
    if( $name == "sparql" ) { $this->looks_legit = true; }
    if( $name == "result" )
    {
        $this->result = array();
    }
    if( $name == "binding" )
    {
        $this->part = $attr["name"];
    }
    if( $name == "uri" || $name == "bnode" )
    {
        $this->part_type = $name;
        $this->chars = "";
    }
    if( $name == "literal" )
    {
        $this->part_type = "literal";
        if( isset( $attr["datatype"] ) )
        {
            $this->part_datatype = $attr["datatype"];
        }
        if( isset( $attr["xml:lang"] ) )
        {
            $this->part_lang = $attr["xml:lang"];
        }
        $this->chars = "";
    }
    if( $name == "variable" )
    {
        $this->fields[] = $attr["name"];
    }
}
```

Now, if you take a look at [SPARQL Query Results XML Format (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-XMLres/#definition), which defines what results should look like, particularly [2.3.2. Boolean Results](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-XMLres/#boolean-results), we see that the result of an ASK query should look like

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
>   ...  head ...
>
>   <boolean>true</boolean>
>
> </sparql>
> ```

sparqllib.php doesn't include anything to look for an element with name "boolean".  It's only designed to handle `select` results, it appears.  That said, the code is licensed under the LGPL, and according to the file header is available on GitHub, so you should be able to fork it and add `ask` support if you want:

```
###############################
# Christopher Gutteridge 2010
#  cjg@ecs.soton.ac.uk
#  LGPL License 
#  http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/sparqllib/
#  https://github.com/cgutteridge/PHP-SPARQL-Lib
###############################
```